# OTP is not coming, I am getting the verification ID and the Testing number is also working

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication

This is the function I am using for to generate OTP and submitting OTP.
The OTP came once, but after that the OTP is not coming.
I even tried 2 different country code and numbers.

```
class AuthService with ChangeNotifier {
  final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
  //Sign In
  String userphone = "";
  String verificationId;
  String errorMessage = "";

  Future verifyPhone(String phonenumber) async {
    final PhoneVerificationFailed verificationFailed =
        (FirebaseAuthException authException) {
      print("Auth Exception is ${authException.message}");
    };

    final PhoneCodeSent codeSent =
        (String verificationId, [int forceResendingToken]) async {
      print("verification id is $verificationId");
      this.verificationId = verificationId;
    };

    final PhoneCodeAutoRetrievalTimeout codeAutoRetrievalTimeout =
        (String verificationId) {
      this.verificationId = verificationId;
    };

    await _auth.verifyPhoneNumber(
      phoneNumber: "+7" + phonenumber,
      verificationCompleted: null,
      verificationFailed: verificationFailed,
      codeSent: codeSent,
      codeAutoRetrievalTimeout: codeAutoRetrievalTimeout,
      timeout: const Duration(seconds: 60),
    );
  }

  Future signIn({@required String smsCode, context}) async {
    AuthCredential authCredential = PhoneAuthProvider.credential(
      verificationId: verificationId,
      smsCode: smsCode,
    );
    UserCredential result = await _auth.signInWithCredential(authCredential);
    User user = result.user;
    await checkUser(result);
    return _userFromFirebase(user);
  }
  }
}
```

The custom Button I am using to trigger the generate otp.
I tried on emulator as well as on my Real Device.

```
CustomButton(
                buttonName: "Generate OTP",
                function: () async {
                  if (_formKeySignIn.currentState.validate() &&
                      phonenumber.length == 10) {
                    Provider.of<AuthService>(context, listen: false).userphone =
                        phonenumber;
                    
                    Provider.of<AuthService>(context, listen: false)
                        .verifyPhone(phonenumber);

                    widget.changeView();
                  } else {
                    setState(() {
                      error = "Please enter a valid phone number";
                    });
                  }
                },
              ),
```

Comment: try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/70003131/12767429

Comment: sorry, doesn't help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code is correct! The mistake I was doing was, I also have to add the SHA Codes from the App Signing Section from the Play Publisher to the Firebase along with your apps SHA code. Then download the Google services json file again and replace your apps json file and generate the app bundle again.