# OTP [firebase_auth/unknown] null

Tags: flutter, firebase-authentication

I searched for days but couldn't find why am I getting this error.

```
E/FirebaseAuth(21984): [SmsRetrieverHelper] SMS verification code request failed: unknown status code: 17499 Error code:39
I/flutter (21984): [firebase_auth/unknown] null
```

i receive this exception when i use my country phone number(Sudan) but when i add another country phone number they receive the SMS verification code.

1.i enabled the Phone Sign-in method in my firebase console.

2.added SHA1 and SHA256 of google play console,signingReport and even key store in my firebase console and uploaded the new google services.json .

3.enabled the Android DeviceCheck API for my project in google cloud console.

4.enabled play integrity in app check.

any help!
thank you in advance.

Comment: try this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70003131/12767429

Answer (score 0):

It seems that there is no way around it, due to the sanctions exposed in Sudan firebase or in fact all google services will not work unless you use a VPN.

Try with [sinch](https://www.sinch.com/) or [twilio](https://www.twilio.com/)